# Can ff object do this ff_object %in% ff_object?

Tags: r

I have two ff objects A and B (from package **ff**), all integer list

```
   A has 1656644 rows while B hase 202897 rows
   I want to get vector C <- A %in% B
```

But  C = logical(0)

Is there any way do %in% operations fast with two ff objects

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Have you looked at %in% from package ffbase?

Comment: I thoungh that ff was base on ffbase...due to it's name...ffbase..

Answer (score 0):

use `match()` , `%in%` is the binary version of `match()`.